# Error following first Theano program example

Tags: theano

I'm totally new to theano and following this simple intro exercise to theano found here: http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/introduction.html#introduction

The idea is to simply declare some tensor variables and wrap them in a function, it is the most simple thing you could possibly do with theano

the exact code is:

```
import theano
from theano import tensor

# declare two symbolic floating-point scalars
a = tensor.dscalar()
b = tensor.dscalar()

# create a simple expression
c = a + b

# convert the expression into a callable object that takes (a,b)
# values as input and computes a value for c
f = theano.function([a,b], c)

# bind 1.5 to 'a', 2.5 to 'b', and evaluate 'c'
assert 4.0 == f(1.5, 2.5)
```

However, I get this traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 13, in <module>
    f = theano.function([a,b], c)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/theano/compile/function.py", line 223, in function
    profile=profile)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/theano/compile/pfunc.py", line 512, in pfunc
    on_unused_input=on_unused_input)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/theano/compile/function_module.py", line 1312, in orig_function
    defaults)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/theano/compile/function_module.py", line 1181, in create
    _fn, _i, _o = self.linker.make_thunk(input_storage=input_storage_lists)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/theano/gof/link.py", line 434, in make_thunk
    output_storage=output_storage)[:3]
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/theano/gof/vm.py", line 847, in make_all
    no_recycling))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/theano/gof/op.py", line 606, in make_thunk
    output_storage=node_output_storage)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/theano/gof/cc.py", line 948, in make_thunk
    keep_lock=keep_lock)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/theano/gof/cc.py", line 891, in __compile__
    keep_lock=keep_lock)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/theano/gof/cc.py", line 1314, in cthunk_factory
    key = self.cmodule_key()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/theano/gof/cc.py", line 1032, in cmodule_key
    c_compiler=self.c_compiler(),
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/theano/gof/cc.py", line 1090, in cmodule_key_
    sig.append('md5:' + theano.configparser.get_config_md5())
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/theano/configparser.py", line 146, in get_config_md5
    ['%s = %s' % (cv.fullname, cv.__get__()) for cv in all_opts]))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/theano/configparser.py", line 146, in <listcomp>
    ['%s = %s' % (cv.fullname, cv.__get__()) for cv in all_opts]))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/theano/configparser.py", line 273, in __get__
    val_str = self.default()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/theano/tensor/blas.py", line 282, in default_blas_ldflags
    if GCC_compiler.try_flags(["-lblas"]):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/theano/gof/cmodule.py", line 1852, in try_flags
    flags=flag_list, try_run=False)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/theano/gof/cmodule.py", line 1799, in try_compile_tmp
    os.write(fd, src_code)
TypeError: ('The following error happened while compiling the node', Elemwise{add,no_inplace}(<TensorType(float64, scalar)>, <TensorType(float64, scalar)>), '\n', "'str' does not support the buffer interface")
```

My only thought is that it may be python3 related, but that should not be the case. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Theano code base do not work out of the box for python2 and python3. It need to get converted. This is done during the installation of Theano. When installed via pip, this is done automatically. If you cloned/downloded the source code, you need to install it with:

```
python setup.py install
```

Here is a Theano ticket with more information:

https://github.com/Theano/Theano/issues/2317

Also, for python 3 support, you should use the development version line the other answer:

```
pip3 install --upgrade --no-deps git+git://github.com/Theano/Theano.git
```

But this isn't related to BLAS as it is written.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is not including the BLAS in the most recent version of theano. Solved when you pull the bleeding-edge version:

```
pip3 install --upgrade --no-deps git+git://github.com/Theano/Theano.git
```